# Self hosted VPN with PiHole on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to create a setup where all of my (mobile and home) traffic is encrypted and ad-blocked. The idea is to use this setup:

[image: VPN Setup]

wherein all of my traffic when using the VPN client on my phone or PC is routed through a custom OpenVPN setup running on a AWS EC2 instance. On its way out of the EC2 instance towards the public internet, I want to have a PiHole or equivalent DNS sinkhole filtering requests for blacklisted sites.

It's important that this is configured in such a way that I'm not allowing for a public/open DNS resolver - only traffic coming from through the OpenVPN (and therefore coming from an OpenVPN client that is using one of my keys) should be allowed.

Is this possible? Am I correctly understanding the functionality of all the parts?

How do I set this up? What concepts do I need to understand to make this work?

Comment: why do it on aws when you can self host at your home ?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/fillory/openvpn-pihole-ad-blocking-on-aws-lightsail-for-3-50-mo-7e814eafff84) seems like a good place to start. This is using lightsail not EC2, but if you aren't planning to scale this up much that might be simpler and cheaper.